# @font-face : Must I include the bold variant while using a custom font?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am importing/using a custom font via the "@font-face" rule. On my mac the font seems to show perfectly fine, with and without the weight: "bold".

Although on a windows machine, when bold is used (for the font), either the font not being found or something else is wrong.

Take a look at the top attachment. You will notice the difference.

font used: Futura

Must I be including the variant/weights of the font as well ? Or is there another way, I am supposed to be dealing with custom fonts.

Thanks.

[image: good-bad]

Answer (score 2):

Importing font face is not necessary if you have font on your local machine. When you import font and make it bold (by font-weight: bold) it can rander badly (look bad on website). I prefer importing all various of font to css -- then when i want to use bold i set font-family: 'myfontBold' and font-weight: normal. You can generate font face with css here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Thanks, was wondering if that is best way to do it. It seems so.

Comment: In my opinion it is the bast way if you want to have nice rendered font on front page, but remember that it is not efficient (you have to load all various of font -> time+transfer).

Answer (score 0):

Including the bold font is up to you. Personally I find it unnecessary.

Either way make sure that if you use a bold font you do not set it to bold as well or you will have a double bolded font.

Comment: Oh you mean, include the other font file and import it with a new name ? (e.g. futura-bold) ? Or with the same import/rule can I include the bold font ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t include a bold typeface when defining a downloadable font with `@font-face` and yet use HTML or CSS that causes bolding, you force browsers into using “synthetic bolding”, which usually produces lousy results. The results vary by browser, though.

So the answer is “yes, if you use bolding for text in that font”.

As an aside, I don’t think you can legally use Futura as a downloadable font.